# NodeJs await is only valid in async function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set some data in firestore using this node js code :

```
const db = admin.firestore();
const allDB = db.collection("like").doc("all").collection("movies");
const s1 = db.collection("like").doc("all");
await s1.set({
  type: ["all"],
});
```

running the file in console : `node file.js`

Gives me this error :

```
await s1.set({
^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: In the future, I suggest doing a web search before posting your question.  Many times the question has already been asked, and you can be helped by looking at the existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in async function

```
async function run(){
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const allDB = db.collection("like").doc("all").collection("movies");
  const s1 = db.collection("like").doc("all");
  await s1.set({
    type: ["all"],
  });
}

run().catch(e => { console.error(e); process.exit(-1); })
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use it inside an async function, this will work:

```
const doSomething = async () => {
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const allDB = db.collection("like").doc("all").collection("movies");
  const s1 = db.collection("like").doc("all");
  await s1.set({
    type: ["all"],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like in the answer above, you just need to make an async function by using the `async` title thing, then naming a function with the stuff inside it